# Extract information from RTF file in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, extract, rtf

We have many RTF files which we need to upload in Oracle EBS to their respective category. To do so we need to read some info stored in Document Properties of RTF file. These fields are Title, Subject, Author, Company and Category.

When we open a RTF file in notepad, we can see this info but not sure how to extract it using linux command. Using grep wasn't very successful.

I am pasting here part of RTF file which holds this info

```
\mwrapIndent1440\mintLim0\mnaryLim1}{\info**{\title ^XXSLS_GBL_ORDACK^}****{\subject XXSLS}****{\author ^es_ES,es_FR,ES_IT,ES_de^}**{\doccomm $Header: XXSLS_GBL_ORDACK_ES_ES.rtf $}
{\operator }{\creatim\yr2012\mo11\dy11\hr14\min3}{\revtim\yr2013\mo3\dy2\hr10\min43}{\version24}{\edmins361}{\nofpages4}{\nofwords725}{\nofchars14202}{\*\manager }{\*\company }**{\*\category ^BD^}**{\nofcharsws14898}
{\vern32773}}{\*\userprops {\propname _DocHome}\proptype3{\staticval -974575144}}{\*\xmlnstbl {\xmlns1 http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml}}\paperw11850\paperh18144\margl851\margr851\margt851\margb0\gutter0\ltrsect
```

Can someone please suggest how we can extract this info as follows:

```
Title=^XXSLS_GBL_ORDACK^
Subject=XXSLS
Author=^es_ES,es_FR,ES_IT,ES_de^
Category=^BD^
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grep can do it with the -E (advanced regex) flag and -o (only matching output) flag.

```
 title=`grep -oE 'title [^\}]+' file.rtf | sed 's/title //g'`
 echo "title=$title"
 subject=`grep -oE 'subject [^\}]+' file.rtf | sed 's/subject //g'`
 echo "subject=$subject"
 author=`grep -oE 'author [^\}]+' file.rtf | sed 's/author //g'`
 echo "author=$author"
 category=`grep -oE 'category [^\}]+' file.rtf | sed 's/category //g'`
 echo "category=$category"
```

I get

```
title=^XXSLS_GBL_ORDACK^
subject=XXSLS
author=^es_ES,es_FR,ES_IT,ES_de^
category=^BD^
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen. On command prompt these commands work perfectly. But when I try to assign output to a variable like this TITLE=`grep -oE '\{\\title[^\}]+' file.rtf` then it returns nothing (null). Any idea why?

Comment: How can I assign result of **grep -oE '\{\\title[^\}]+' file.rtf** to a variable? It is not working the way we normally do like `VAR_TITLE='grep -oE '\{\\title[^\}]+' file.rtf'`. This way variable has null value.

Comment: To assign the result of a command to a variable in bash you need to enclose the command in backticks.   I can't show you here because they have special meaning to the comment formatting.  Replace the single quotes in what you are trying with back ticks.

Comment: You may think that what a dumb question he has asked but truly that's what exactly I did and result in variable is null. Never seen this happening before. I used single-quote in my comment above because info within backticks was being treated as a code snippet.

Comment: I edited my answer with code that puts it into variables and displays the variables.  I'm not sure why, but variable assignment wasn't working when the text started with a open brace.